# LWJGL in Visual Studio (possible)?

Tags: java, lwjgl, ide

I switched from XNA and C# to LWJGL and Java about 14 months ago. Inherently, this called for a switch in IDE. I started using eclipse because I have also done some basic Android development in the past.

I soon switched to Netbeans - Eclipse is just too primitive. After using netbeans for about six months, I've started looking over the fence at Visual Studio 11, toying with Metro apps for windows 8.

**Now I want to know, is there any known way to use Visual Studio for LWJGL?**

Comment: `Eclipse is just too primitive` I have heard *many* things and opinions about Eclipse, but 'too primitive' is new.

Comment: After calling Eclipse primitive you changed to Netbeans?

Comment: Heh, I just switched yesterday from Netbeans to Eclipse. So far, much better.

Comment: For anyone remotely interested, I settled into IntelliJ IDEA. Its very, very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio has no support for Java. There are some [hacks](http://improve.dk/archive/2007/09/29/compiling-java-in-visual-studio.aspx) to using VS as an over-sized text editor but this won't give you any debugging capabilities and you will have to write your own build scripts. I have found no LWJGL ports to C# so I think the answer on your question is No.

However there are OpenGL wrappers for C#, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536065/using-opengl-with-c). And if you are just interested in games you can also try XNA which provides a bit higher abstraction above DirectX. There are even more alternatives to 3D in C#/C++/VB. Like SlimDX, MonoXNA and Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use Visual Studio as a text editor and trigger custom build steps, but then you would lose in my opinion one of the most important benefit of Java, strong IDE support.

If you didn't like Eclipse, you should try [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Whenever I'm programming in Visual Studio, I really miss IntelliJ.

Comment: Although I don't miss IDEA when I use Visual Studio, I do think that IDEA is the only free (the express versions) IDE for JAVA that really works well. Eclipse is a mess and Netbeans is functional but slow.